Collaborator asking for multiple figures for thesis?
A PhD student who was a co-author on a previous paper (helped with 1 experiment) is asking for the raw files for multiple extensive figures to use in their PhD thesis presentation.
I created each of these figures and ran all experiments, they did not help.
Any advice for whether I should provide the figures and if so, under what stipulations? I do feel somewhat uncomfortable providing given the situation.

What is your status? The answer will be very different if you are a professor or a MA student assisting in the project. If you are a professor you are in a position to teach the PhD student, if you are a MA student you cannot. If you are a fellow PhD student than that can get awkward. In those cases I would escalate and get the PI involved. Notice escalating is just a bureaucratic term and has nothing to do with how serious a conflict is and only with whose job it is to decide something.

Former colleague who is still a PhD student, I’m a new professor now

Perhaps this is my field, but I don't understand why you would ever turn down a request to use a figure in a PhD defense?

@AzorAhai-him- A figure needs proper attribution, maybe even a citation if published elsewhere. Handing over the raw data is the basis of a new image and the creator can claim it is their own, neglecting the work going into the experiment.

@usr1234567 I know that. Defense slides are not publishing. The OP has given no indication the student doesn't plan to properly attribute anything. I also read "raw files" to mean the uncompressed PNG or Inkscape file or something; but I concede your interpretation is also plausible.

What kind of thesis is this?  A single book, or a collection of papers?
If it's the later, then it would be normal for a student to need the raw image files of all figures from the collaborative papers included in the thesis so that all the papers can be put into the same format in the formatting process.  The papers will be included with all authors listed, so there's no issue of attribution.
If it's the former, then the figures should be included with a reference to the original paper in the figure caption just as any previously published figure which is used should be, whether it comes from a paper the student was involved with or not.  (Note in this case if the thesis is formerly published then the student may need to apply for copyright permissions from the journals to reproduce previously published figures, just like you would have to with a review paper).

Very clarifying, thank you. The figures have been previously published & copyrighted in my thesis. So do I just provide and say sure - just include “reproduced or adapted from X with permission” ?

Will you be interested to share if you are given due credit?
If not, you can have a dialogue and make them understand that you are not the owner of those figures as you did not perform the experiments. This is unethical practice to use the figures from the experiment that someone else has performed.
You can, however, teach them how to generate those figures, if that could help them and they have a learning attitude.
If things go bad, you can involve their supervisor to mediate in this matter.

I don't understand: the OP is the owner and did create the figures. Also it is not unethical at all to use other persons' figures as long as you give due credit, which the student did not say the woudln't do?

I think this comes to mutual understanding and relationship between you guys. I once faced similar situation, but my colleague happily shared some of the figures. But I only asked a few of them.
